# Is EnableViewState property inherited by child controls?

Tags: asp.net

```
<div runat="server" enableviewstate="false">

    <div runat="server" enableviewstate="false"></div>

</div>
```

What happends if I won't set the enableviewstate property for the second div. Is it inherited from it's parent or not ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it get inherited form the parent one.

`EnableViewState` property on any container will override the behavior of all controls within that contain